# How to take first N records and add remaining records value in single list object without multiple ToList?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

I have a class like below :

```
public class StatusTypeViewModel
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int Stats { get; set; }
    }
    
public List<StatusTypeViewModel> GetStatusData()
{
    //linq query
}


public ActionResult Get()
{
   var statusData = GetStatusData();
   var topTwo = statusData.Take(2).ToList();

 
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is to create a result like below :

1. Take first 2
2. Exclude the first 2 and sum up the value of all "Stats" property of the resulting records with "Miscellaneous" status.

Data returned from GetStatusData method:

```
Status    Stats
A         2
B         4
C         6
D         8
```

**Final Result:**

```
Status           Stats
A                 2
B                 4
Miscellaneous     14
```

My concern is I am right now doing multiple ToList and probably looking to do it in a single loop or in a more elegant way instead of doing multiple `.ToList()`

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code works. It is done in two parts, though.

```
var statuses = new List<StatusTypeViewModel> {
    new StatusTypeViewModel { Status = "A", Stats = 2},
    new StatusTypeViewModel { Status = "B", Stats = 4},
    new StatusTypeViewModel { Status = "C", Stats = 6},
    new StatusTypeViewModel { Status = "D", Stats = 8},
};

var misc = new StatusTypeViewModel { 
    Status = "Miscellaneous", 
    Stats = statuses.Skip(2).Sum(s => s.Stats) 
};

var result = statuses.Take(2).Concat(new[] { misc });
```

You could also do it using [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) like so:

```
var misc = statuses.Skip(2)
    .GroupBy(
        s => 0, // give everything the same key, so just one group
        s => s.Stats,
        (key, stats) => new StatusTypeViewModel
        {
            Status = "Miscellaneous",
            Stats = stats.Sum()
        });

var result = statuses.Take(2).Concat(misc);
```

Personally, I find the first version easier to read.

In both cases, if you really wanted to do it in a single statement you could just inline the `misc` variable. Again, though, I find it easier to read when it's split out.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple linq statement

statusData.Skip(2).Sum(x=> x.Stats)

Comment: This does not produce the expected result

Comment: bar result = statusData.Take(2).ToList(); var misc = statusData.Skip(2).Sum(x=> x.Stats); result.Add(misc);

Comment: You can't put a newline in because you accidentally replied to your answer rather than editing it.